# Assign unserialize Laravel object to JS array

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have serialize object returning from Controller to blade view in laravel like:

```
"a:3:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"4";i:2;s:1:"6";}"
```

from my blade view I use this JS code block to get those value as array.

```
var branches = {{unserialize($preliminary->branches)}};
```

But in there I'm getting error saying

> expression expected

any suggestions to solve this situation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `json_encode` on top of your `unserialize`.

E.g.

```
var branches = {{json_encode(unserialize($preliminary->branches))}};
```

`unserialize` is giving you a PHP object, which you are trying to inject directly into JS. By passing it through `json_encode`you convert it to a string javascript can grok.

Comment: Just make sure to replace {{}} with {!!  !!}}